# Subtracting columns of Timestamps gives me TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
                      dt1               dt2
0 2011-09-12 09:57:03.839546  2011-09-12 09:51:29.332474
1 2011-09-12 09:57:03.841132  2011-09-12 09:55:29.332774
2 2011-09-12 10:57:28.581049  2011-09-12 10:55:29.332774
3 2011-09-12 10:57:28.581049  2011-09-12 10:55:29.332774
4 2011-09-12 10:57:28.582636  2011-09-12 10:55:29.332774
```

The class of the entries is `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`. When I do

```
df['dt1'][:]-df['dt2'][:]
```

I am fine, but this

```
df['dt1']-df['dt2']
```

fails with the following error

```
TypeError: Argument 'values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Series)
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: That's expected behavior. Later one is for arithmatical operation.

Comment: So, how can I subtract columns of timestamps then?

Comment: Does my answer with the good subtraction fit your needs ?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting to `datetime64` can fix it.

```
df['dt1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt1'])
df['dt2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt2'])

df['dt1']-df['dt2']

0   00:05:34.507072
1   00:01:34.508358
2   00:01:59.248275
3   00:01:59.248275
4   00:01:59.249862
```

Comment: But why am I getting 0 days then? Why is it not showing more granular info on the difference?

Comment: There is an error in your question since you have written `df['dt1']-df['dt1']`. I have modified the answer to compute the difference between `dt1` and `dt2`.